# Handling site wide data in MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've seen this question asked in a couple of places and generally the answer has been "use the ViewBag" which I don't think fits our scenario.

We have a membership site which has common properties (e.g. Account -which contains the user's account settings) and I would like to use that in both the Views and _layout.cshtml (e.g. to allow the user to change the colour scheme).

In the views, we're inheriting from a base view model but how can we get access to this data in the standard pages e.g. About Us etc which don't have any associated view model? I've tried creating a partial view which passes the data through in it's controller but that didn't work

Comment: If your architecture requires a View Model, why not create one?

Comment: We've got a base view model for the various views but it's the common pages that I'm not clear on (e.g. in the default MVC project these would be Home, About Us and Contact Us). Using a ViewModel there doesn't "feel" right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main options are:
1. Consider implementing a profile provider - the settings are then available everywhere, use an Action Filter
2. use your own custom context assigned to the current request/user
3. use a base controller/base viewmodel for the pages that don't have them
4. use a global action filter
5. viewdata/session
See some details at:
[ASP.NET MVC 3 layout ViewBag data across all child views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207289/asp-net-mvc-3-layout-viewbag-data-across-all-child-views)

if you already have this working and need access in an "About Us" page and don't want another view model (why not?) then an action filter would be the way to go - unless this is a typical aspx page in that case you are left without options 3/4 above.

Comment: Ok thanks Adam, it's not so much that I don't want another ViewModel, it just didn't feel right, will go that route.

Comment: do not use a base controller ...it's sloppier, use an action filter if using MVC 3

Comment: Was simply providing a list of main options, action filter is provided in the list above. Some may prefer the controller for additional reasons (for ex. caching code in there, so centralized place for share functionality related to a single controller instance )